# I have an error while moving to 'Setup' screen from 'Home' page in SF sandbox

Tags: visualforce, javascript, administration

while moving from Home to Setup page, navigating from button at right upper corner in sales-cloud enterprise edition. I am facing this from last 1 hour.

[image: I'm continuously facing an error and Setup page isn't loading. It keeps blinking with error message. I also attach the error message screenshot. On refresh several times,it's still the same.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try clearing your cache and also try changing your locale. 
There was a similar [known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000E151AAC&title=unable-to-access-setup-pages-in-lightning-experience-when-locale-is-portuguese-brazil).